# How to execute Laravel controler method by Angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

Let's say I have an laravel controller that contains one method that parsing value from other sites. On client side I'm using Angular. When user presses button it have to execute this Laravel controller method and value that parsed by this method have to fill an input field in form. Im completely  new in angular. So is it possible to execute this laravel method from angular? If it is possible can you give some examples how can I achieve this?

Comment: Yes, just make an AJAX request. See documentation for [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is just a little example to show how to use $http to transport data. I'm not worked with laravel much.

**view.html**

```
<html ng-app = 'myAPP'>
   <head>
    //include required css or js files 
   </head>
   <body>
         <div ng-controller = 'MainCtrl'>
             <button ng-click = 'sendData()'>Click me</button>
         </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
angular.module('myAPP').controller('MainCtrl',['$scope','$http','$log',function($scope,$http){

$scope.sendData = function(){
   $http.post('url',data).success(function(returnData){});
}

}]);
```

after http post, from laravel controller it must be catch those data in jason format you either can use it in that format or you can decode it and then use it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try it later.